# How do I set a submenu to open on a desktop hover and click on a mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This is my javascript code. I have a fa fa icon that I need to click on my mobile to open the submenu. When I switch from the desktop to the mobile display in the browser, the fa fa element does not get an event, only when I refresh the page does it get an event.

```
if ($(window).width() < 992) {
    $('.toggle-submenu').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().next().next('.submenu').slideToggle();
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#">News
      <i class="toggle-submenu submenu-arrow fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
   </a>
   <span class="category-home"></span>
   <ul class="submenu">
      <li>
         <a href="#">Najnovije vesti</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
 </li>
```

MOBILE CSS

```
                ul.submenu{
                        display: none;
                        padding: 0 0 20px 30px;
                        list-style: none;
                        background: #FF9600;
                        li{
                            margin-bottom: 10px;
                            a{
                                color: #fff;
                                font-family: $roboto-medium;
                                font-size: 18px;
                            }
                            &:last-of-type{
                                margin-bottom: 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

DESTOP CSS

```
                    li{
                        width: auto;
                        display: flex;
                        height: 100%;
                        &:hover ul.submenu{
                            display: block;
                        }
                        ul.submenu{
                            min-width: 185px !important;
                            display: none;
                            position: absolute;
                            top: 100%;
                            padding: 20px;
                            list-style: none;
                            background: #FF9600;
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug with the browser. For mobile, you can use touch events instead of click events.

Comment: Is that `CSS` or `SCSS`?

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal scss

Comment: @UrosRakic So why have you mentioned `CSS`